# Resource Files in CF - Not Embedded

Tags: compact-framework

I have a PPC2003 project in VS2005. I have added a resource file (SomeResources.resx) to the project. I can access the test string I have in the file by using `My.Resources.SomeResources.MyTestString` (I am using the default *Custom Tool Name* that VS provides).

When the *Build Action* property of the is set to `Embedded Resource`, the application references the `MyTestString` successfully.

But I **do not** want to embed the file, so that it's string values can be modified after it has been deployed/installed.

I, therefore, changed the *Build Action* to `Content`, so that the file gets copied out to the device for potential future manipulation. When I call `MyTestString` I get the following error:

> MissingManifestResourceException Stack Trace: at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet() at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet() at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet() at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString() at MyApp.My.Resources.SomeResources.get_MyTestString() at MyApp.fMain.fMain_Load() at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad() at System.Windows.Forms.Form._SetVisibleNotify() at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible() at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run() at MyApp.fMain.Main()

As the file is not embedded, do I maybe need to manually load it first? If so, how? Any other ideas? Is it not possible to do what I'm after achieving and should I just create my own XML file/reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources (resx files) are specifically designed to be compiled into the application.  If you want it to be an editable content file on the target, then you have to approach it differently and use something like an XML file and wrap that with accessors (akin to the Configuration namespace stuff in the full framework).